# Tuleap Project Creation Error

Tags: php, tuleap

im using the latest version of Tuleap 6.12 after registering a new project and admin approves it the following error occurs:

> The shared group you are trying to enable does not exist.

But the project was created and was able to access and configure the project details.
Will that issue have any other impact on the projects.

Comment: Do you use CentOS 5, CentOS 6 or Debian?
Look in /var/log/httpd/error_log (on CentOS) to find more info on your error. Don't forget to edit/complement your post here when you find what's wrong.

Comment: Plus: where did you get this error (console, web, etc). A link to a screenshot is a plus

Comment: OS-Centos6.5.I get this eror on tuleap admin main tab section.   [Wed Apr 23 03:36:02 2014] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Wed Apr 23 03:36:02 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.3 SVN/1.6.11 mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Apr 23 11:07:09 2014] [error] [client "ip"] File does not exist: /usr/share/tuleap/src/www/www, referer: http://fresh.tuleap.com/projects/testA/